# Recognising Hashtags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, hashtag

I need to recognise hashtags (#example) in a string using javascript and change them to

```
<a href='#/tags/example'>example</a>
```

at the moment I am using this code:

```
var string = '#hello This is an #example of some text';

string.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<a href='#/tags/$2'>$2</a>");
```

however the value of $2 still includes the # character and I need to omit this for the url

Comment: Try `/(^|\s)#([a-z\d-]+)/ig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `#` outside the capturing group:

`/(^|\s)#([a-z\d-]+)/ig`